# Failing to connect my ChatRoomScreen to the navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, frontend

Code Below

SyntaxError: /Users/suspect/Desktop/Dev/chatApp/Messenger/navigation/index.tsx: Did not expect a type annotation here. (31:50)

29 | function RootNavigator() {
30 |   return (

> 31 |     <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={( headerShown : false)} >
> |                                                   ^
> 32 |       <Stack.Screen name="ChatRoom" component={ChatRoomScreen} options={{ headerShown: true}} />
> 33 |       <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
> 34 |       <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />

ABI44_0_0RCTFatal
__37-[ABI44_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
**CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0

I am working on a messaging app, while creating the RootNavigator Function i keep getting a Type annotation error and failing to compile Ive tried to debug and getting no luck :(

````
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as React from 'react';
import { ColorSchemeName } from 'react-native';

import NotFoundScreen from '../screens/NotFoundScreen';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../types';
import LinkingConfiguration from './LinkingConfiguration';

import ChatRoomScreen from '../screens/ChatRoomScreen';

export default function Navigation({ colorScheme, }: { colorScheme: ColorSchemeName;}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={LinkingConfiguration}
      theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
      >
        <RootNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();



function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={( headerShown : false)} >
      <Stack.Screen name="ChatRoom" component={ChatRoomScreen} options={{ headerShown: true}} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}```
````

Comment: `{( headerShown : false)}` parenthesis should be curly braces `{{ headerShown : false}}`